# How to turn off "Safari From Mac" on Dock when two computers are near each other

Tags: safari

I am getting this weird effect where if I bring my computer next to another computer, then I have a second safari icon.

[image]

Clicking on it opens the safari that is *on the other computer* on my computer.  This is extremely unsettling for me because that tells me my safari can be viewed on other computers.

How do I turn off this feature?  I am looking for a solution to disables this on both computers (when my computer is next to another computer, a second safari *should NOT show up*).  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **System Preferences > General** on both Macs, uncheck *"Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices"*.

On iOS devices, uncheck the similar option at **Settings > General > AirPlay & Handoff**.

Note that only devices signed in to your iCloud account can work together in this way. Your Safari usage cannot be viewed by any other computers, so there is no 'security' risk. The devices also have to be physically close.

Also note that your browser history may still be shared across your devices on the same iCloud account anyway.

The purpose of the feature is that when you have more than one Mac, iPhone, iPad, etc, you can 'Hand-off' activities from one to the other.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209455

Comment: Thank you; the solution worked for me.  And to be sure, Handoff is different from AirDrop, correct?

Comment: @QuantumDot It uses similar connection technology, but yes, it's a different thing. You can AirDrop to computers that aren't using your AppleID.